# in android is it possible to find latitude and longitude using wifi?

Tags: android, android-wifi

In my Application i need to use user's current location.
Through GPS, i knw how to do it but can any body have idea that how it can be done using Wifi?
Pls do my help,

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the Android [Obtaining User Location](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/obtaining-user-location.html) documentation - especially the usage of the [NETWORK_PROVIDER](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#NETWORK_PROVIDER).